# Time-Currency Tokens

Tags: solidity

How would you go about creating a token that has a value based on time? (Time-currency Tokens)

What would be the solidity code be? I can't find much examples on this.

Thanks.!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_currency)? You can do this in more or less the same way the past attempts have: issue a certificate (token) whenever someone does some work that needs to be credited and give it to them. This requires there to be a central issuing authority. And, as you can see, that really isn't any different than any existing token. You could also just create a lot of ERC20 tokens at the start (more than you'll ever need) and assign them to yourself as the central issuing authority.